# Package nwjs app into a single exe

Tags: windows, exe, archive, nwjs

I have created an installer program for my application using NWJS. I need to package the NWJS app into a single exe. I was going to use windows iexpress becasue that would provide exactly the function I need, however I can't use that because it does not support directorys inside the archive and even with the app html files packaged into package.nw NWJS still requires the locales directory to run and also iexpress has some security flaws.

Basically I need something like this:

1: it is a single portable executable file which contains some sort of archive with the nwjs files in it.

2: when the exe is run it extracts the archive to a temporary directory and runs nwjs.

3: when nwjs exits it deletes the temp directory.

So far I have not found any way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and solved it myself by using Enigma Virtual Box.

http://enigmaprotector.com/en/downloads.html